# mergExt - mergReader

Tags: iphone, livecode

I've a problem with `mergReader` function.
In my iOS app I use a `mobilePick` function, 
before I call `mergReader` the viewing of `mobilPick` is well in center of the screen 
but after `mergReader` called the next use of `mobilPick` put to left position the Picker into the screen.

after calling  mergReader screenshot:
[After](http://www.borzini.it/mobilepick_after.png)

before calling  mergReader screenshot:
[Before](http://www.borzini.it/mobilepick_before.png)

Any hints?

Thanks,
Paolo

Comment: Can you tell me what version of LC and if you are using a fullscreenMode? I really can't think what mergReader could be doing to cause this issue.

Comment: Using LC 6.5 Commercial version.

Comment: do you get the same behaviour when you use LC 6.1.3?

Comment: I've tested with LC 6.1.3 build 2052 and the result is the same.